# HttpPost not working!

Tags: android, http, http-post

I am trying to write something to an empty file on my apache server

```
myClient= new DefaultHttpClient();

StringEntity myString = new StringEntity("important message");
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.218.211/myfile");
httpPost.setEntity(myString);

HttpResponse response = myClient.execute(httpPost);
```

The reponse returns "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" so it does find the file

I tried removing the file and it returned Error 404

I read apache's docs and looks like am doing it right "i think"

My problem is... the contents of the file do not get updated!

An example would be great!

Comment: What programming language and framework did you write your Web app in? Have you tested the Web app using other clients, like `curl`? In other words, why is this an Android question, rather than a Web server or Web app question?

Comment: I have to agree with CommonsWare, the problem here is most likely in what you are doing server side when the post request is recieved.

Comment: the server is apache2 on Ubuntu 10.10, i can access it from my browser. i can also read and parse XML files from the server however i dont know how to write to an XML file on the server. "myfile" in my question is the actual XML file, is that the way it's meant to be or should i have like a php script or something to handle the http posts? i am as noob as they get with android but i do apologize for any inconvenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = "http://10.0.218.211/post.php"; 

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);  

try {  
        **// Add your data <-**
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "important message 1"));  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message2", "important message 2"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

        // Execute HTTP Post Request  
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);  

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
        / TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        }
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

$message = $_POST['message'];

// Load XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("myfile.xml"); 

 //In this line it create a SimpleXMLElement object with the source of the XML file.
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());

//The following lines will add a new child and others child inside the previous child created.
$item = $sxe->addChild("item");
$item->addChild("message", $message);

//This next line will overwrite the original XML file with new data added
$sxe->asXML("myfile.xml"); 

?>
```

**myfile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <item>
        <message>Important Message</messagee>
    </item>
</data>
```

Comment: thank for the quick answer, still nothing appears on my xml file and the response still is HTTP/1.1 200 OK, "myfile" is the actual xml file, am i supposed to post differently like to php?

Comment: ur the man bro, but i still get HTTP/1.1 200 OK from response and the file is still empty. i created post.php and copied both php and android codes but still no use :(

Comment: i'll try the new php script u put

Comment: it gives me 500 Internal Server Error now

Comment: i got apache2 with php-5 installed on my server

Comment: i changed </messagee> to </message> now it gives me HTTP/1.1 200 OK again but still no changes to the message "i put <message>Old Message</messagee> in the file to see if it changes

Comment: <message>Old Message</message>

Comment: i just tried to run a php script that writes a txt file from my browser, it couldn't. i think the problem is with my apache2 server allowing read only "i think" i'll look into it, thanks heaps for ur help! am almost there

Comment: Did you add uses-permission to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> i tried to run a write file php script from my pc browser, the line $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); shows "can't open file on my browser. i did check the file name in the script and i am sure am doing it right, the whole script is... 

<?php

$myFile = "myfile.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>

Comment: wohooo, just needed to set permissions on my apache server and it all works!!! thank you SO SO SO SO SO MUCH BRO!!!!!! you're a life saver!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you may want to call setcontentType.
For example

```
StringEntity myString = new StringEntity("important message");
myString.setContentType("application/json");//or what ever your server expected
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.218.211/myfile");
httpPost.setEntity(myString);
```